# You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. spring

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

Have an issue starting up a postgresql r2dbs spring boot application. I am getting the below error for this configuration.:

Inside main module:

```
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>myModule.dblib</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

App:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.pack")
@EntityScan("com.pack")
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
@Import(DatabaseConfiguration.class)
public class InventoryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InventoryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InventoryService {

    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;

    public Flux<ItemPojo> getAllItems() {
        return itemRepository.findAllItems()
                             .map(Item::toPojo);
    }
}
```

Repo:

```
    @Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Item, Long> {

    Flux<List<Item>> findByName(String name);

    @Query("select i from Item i")
    Flux<Item> findAllItems();

}
```

Entity:

```
@Data
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public static ItemPojo toPojo(final Item items) {
        return new ItemPojo(items.id, items.name);
    }
}
```

**myModule.dblib:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Database config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration{

    @Value("${spring.data.postgres.host}") private String host;
    @Value("${spring.data.postgres.port}") private int port;
    @Value("${spring.data.postgres.database}") private String database;
    @Value("${spring.data.postgres.username}") private String username;
    @Value("${spring.data.postgres.password}") private String password;

    @Bean
    public PostgresqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                                                    .host(host)
                                                    .port(port)
                                                    .database(database)
                                                    .username(username)
                                                    .password(password)
                                                    .build());
        }
}
```

Error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.


2019-06-18 20:44:50,265 ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed


org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '/api/internal/inventory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'inventoryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inventoryService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/epi/services/inventory/items/InventoryService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)


    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)


    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)


    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)


    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)


    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)


    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)


    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)


    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)


    at com.epi.services.inventory.InventoryApplication.main(InventoryApplication.java:17)


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)


    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)


    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)


    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)


    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)


    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)


    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inventoryService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/epi/services/inventory/items/InventoryService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1171)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)


    ... 27 common frames omitted


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)


    ... 40 common frames omitted


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!


    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:532)


    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)


    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287)


    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)


    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)


    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)


    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.java:123)


    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821)


    at org.springframework.beans.factor
```

Edit 1: New version of repository

```
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Item, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT * from items WHERE name = $1")
    Mono<Item> findByName(String name);

    @Query("SELECT * from items")
    Flux<Item> findAllItems();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following method declared in your repository:

```
Flux<List<Item>> findByName(String name);
```

Probably assuming Spring Data R2dbc would provide an implementation.
But that feature isn't implemented yet, so you have to provide the query yourself.

```
@Query("select * from Item where name = :name")
Flux<List<Item>> findByName(String name);
```

### Update

By now (mid 2021) [query derivation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/#r2dbc.repositories.queries) is supported by R2DBC. So you shouldn't see this problem anymore with a recent version of R2DBC

*Note: On the other method you specify the query `select i from Item i`. I don't think this is valid SQL. It looks a little like JPQL which isn't supported by Spring Data R2DBC*

*Another Note: shouldn't that be `Flux<Item>` anyway?*

Comment: confirmed that the issue is definitely triggered by these methods. I tried replacing them with actual sql queries but still go tthe issue. By commenting them out i was getting this error however : `NoSuchMethodError reactor.core.publisher.Flux.usingWhen`  so there might be an underlying issue

Comment: That doesn't sound like an "underlying issue" that sounds like you have an incompatible version of reactor in your classpath.

Comment: you're right. dependency upgrade fixed that. Any idea how i can get the query methods to work? Updating question to include latest version of repository

Comment: Turns out i needed to upgrade spring-data-commons as well. Thanks

Comment: R2DBC doesn't support query by method yet?

Comment: @AleGallagher Thanks for asking. R2DBC now supports query derivation. I added an update to my answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is an issue with your spring-boot version :
https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/issues/218

Try downgrading your spring-boot version form 2.1.x , to the 2.0.0. Or this can also be because of version compatibility issues of your `spring-data-common` with other dependencies.

Comment: I'm using 2.1.x cause 2.0.x async api's aren't compatible with jdk11. Is there another solution i can work around maybe?